# Is $\cos(2\theta)=\frac{2e^{i\theta}+2e^{-i\theta}}2$ a correct application of Euler's Formula?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that using Euler's Formula we can write cosine like the first expression, but concerning the second expression, is it correct like that?

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}2$$

$$\cos(2\theta)=\frac{2e^{i\theta}+2e^{-i\theta}}2$$

Comment: The operation you are performing is called "substitution", and it means to systematically replace each instance of the substitution variable (in this case, $\color{#00F}\theta$) with the desired replacement (in this case, $\color{#C00}{2\theta}.)\quad$ So, $\displaystyle\cos(\color{#C00}{2\theta})=\frac{e^{i(\color{#C00}{2\theta})}+e^{-i(\color{#C00}{2\theta})}}2.$

Comment: @RyanG nice use of colours!

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not correct. You have to substitute $2\theta$ for $\theta$ which means that
$$
\cos(2\theta) = \frac{e^{2i\theta} + e^{-2i\theta}}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not correct. Since$$\cos\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}2,$$you have$$\cos(2\theta)=\frac{e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta}}2.$$

Comment: Just provided the same answer. :-)

Comment: @MartinVesely Great minds think alike. $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 4):

Expression 1 $\to \cos 0=1$, Expression  2 $\to \cos 0=2>1$.

Can  the second expression  be correct?